# window.app - ol3 - cesium

Tags: 3d, openlayers, cesiumjs

I have a question about use Window.app and OL3Cesium.
My code looks like this

```
window.app = {};
var app = window.app;

var measuring = false;
app.MeasureControl = function(opt_options) {
  var options = opt_options || {};
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.innerHTML = 'M';
  var this_ = this;
  var handleMeasure = function(e) {
    if (!measuring){
        this_.getMap().addInteraction(draw);
        createHelpTooltip();
        createMeasureTooltip();
        measuring = true;
    } else {
        this_.getMap().removeInteraction(draw);
        measuring = false;
        this_.getMap().removeOverlay(helpTooltip);
        this_.getMap().removeOverlay(measureTooltip);
    }
  }
  button.addEventListener('click', handleMeasure, false);
  button.addEventListener('touchstart', handleMeasure, false);
  var element = document.createElement('div');
  element.className = 'measure ol-unselectable ol-control button';
  element.appendChild(button);
  ol.control.Control.call(this, {
    element: element,
    target: options.target
  });
};
ol.inherits(app.MeasureControl, ol.control.Control);
```

This app it works all. And ol3d not works.

```
var ol3d = false;
app.Cesium = function(opt_options) {
  var options = opt_options || {};
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.innerHTML = '3D';
  var this_ = this;

  var ol3d = function(e) {
    ol3d.setEnabled(!ol3d.getEnabled(e));
    var ol3d = new olcs.OLCesium({map: ol2d});
    var scene = ol3d.getCesiumScene();
    var terrainProvider = new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({
      url : '//assets.agi.com/stk-terrain/world'
    });
    scene.terrainProvider = terrainProvider;
  };
  button.addEventListener('click', ol3d, false);
  button.addEventListener('touchstart', ol3d, false);
  var element = document.createElement('div');
  element.className = 'cesium ol-unselectable ol-control button';
  element.appendChild(button);
  ol.control.Control.call(this, {
    element: element,
    target: options.target
  });
};
ol.inherits(app.Cesium, ol.control.Control);

var ol2d = new ol.Map({    
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
    attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
      collapsible: false
    })
  }).extend([
        new app.MeasureControl(),
        new app.Cesium(),
        ]),
    target: 'map',
    layers: [],
    view: new ol.View({})
});
```

});

And MeasureControl it works and Cesium not work. 
Where is a bug ? It is the same properties for all app.

Comment: please  add more explain about your problem to question

Comment: I have bug in "ol3d.setEnabled(!ol3d.getEnabled(e));" bug is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setEnabled' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.ol3d"

Comment: OK i know were is the bug :) Thanks